# Allow to user to Enter only numbers and disable letters

Tags: python, user-interface, numbers, letter

can you help me
I have this code

```
    Label (self.window,width=55,text=":Enter your wight ").pack ()
    self.kg = StringVar ()
    Entry (self.window,width=55, textvariable=self.kg).pack ()
```

And I want to allow user to enter Numbers only
and I want user Enter maximum 3 numbers and maximum The number 250

please help me And Thank you!

Comment: You should use an IntVar() instead of a StringVar().  That will limit to digits.  You can validate the range after they submit the form.

Comment: I want disable letter 
I dont want to enter letter
I want when user press any letter dont show anything

Comment: You can’t check whether an input is a letter without assigning it to something. I’m not sure if this helps but you can use try and except statements while converting the inputs to ints so that it only runs the code if the variables are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Too late but here you go:

```
def comm(self):
    def val():
        try:
            int(entry.get())
            if len(entry.get()) <= 3:
                sum =  250 - int(entry.get())
                if sum < 0:
                    entry.delete(0, 'end')
            else:
                entry.delete(0, 'end')
        except:
            entry.delete(0, 'end')

    root.after(1, val)

entry.bind('<Key>',comm)
```

replace 'entry' with the Entry name of yours, also the same goes for root